# Why is not passing the props to the child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, react-props

I´m trying to pass two values as props from a React component "App" to his child "Todo". I´m passing the values title & completed from a json placeholder API.
The JSON object is correct, i´ve checked that already.

The problem is that the child component only displays the first value "title" not the second one.
Also the React console is showing that my constructor from the childs component is a useless constructor, which i don't understand. I´m supposed to call the constructor with props to use them in the component right?

Thank You.

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

import '../styles/Todo.css'

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            todos: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="todo-list">
                <Todo title="Hello" completed={false}></Todo> // HERE
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Todo.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import "../styles/Todo.css"

class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){ // USELESS CONSTRUCTOR?
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="todo-item">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <p> {this.props.title} </p>
                <p> {this.props.completed} </p> // NOT DISPLAYING
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have `state` but empty constructor it is `useless` and better to remove it.

About the value not displaying, `completed` is `boolean` value, you can do this.

```
<p> {this.props.completed.toString()} </p> // NOT DISPLAYING
```

Comment: Anyways, I´m supposed to call the constructor always I want to use the props I´ve passed from its parent, doesnt I? @ravibagul91

Comment: No. If you have `state` or `function to bind` then only you need a constructor otherwise it is better to remove it. Even it is better to use functional component in that case.

Comment: Check out the simplified code using functional component - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-xn9y0?fontsize=14

Comment: Understood. Thank You! @ravibagul91

Answer (score 1):

```
<p> {this.props.completed} </p> // NOT DISPLAYING
```

It is not displaying because the value you pass to it is **boolean**. Apparently react doesn't render boolean values. You can convert it to string using `toString()` though if you want "false" to appear.

The warning about your constructor is that you aren't doing anything in it, hence its useless - and you can remove it.

Comment: @Michalistico Yeah I mentioned that it wouldn't work because it is boolean, check updated answer.